# How to get the return result of a Flutter method in an iOS Widget Extension

Tags: ios, flutter

I have built a flutter app with sqlite, now I wanna to show the results from sqlite with iOS 14 widget extension.

I have add follow codes in **main.dart**

```dart
final MethodChannel channel = MethodChannel('your_channel_name');

channel.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) async {
  if (call.method == 'your_method_name') {
  debugPrint("Result from Flutter");
  return "Result from Flutter";
  }
});
```

I have tested with codes in **AppDelegate.swift**

```swift
let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "your_channel_name", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+5) {
          channel.invokeMethod("your_method_name", arguments: nil) { result in
              if let flutterResult = result as? String {
                  print("Result from Flutter: \(flutterResult)")
              }
          }
      }
```

It works when some seconds delay.

But how can I deal with the iOS widget extension? Can I call flutter function in widget directly?

Thanks